# Plotting data with 4 columns!

Tags: plotting

I'd like 3Dplot a list of data with `4` columns (these are mesh outputs):

```
x1 y1 z1 Dose1
x2 y2 z2 Dose2
.
.
.
```

which command i should to use??

Comment: Image3D is a possibility. But I'd advise you to do at least some basic searching through the docs before posting questions.

Comment: You could try using Graphics3D to place a little sphere at {x1,y1,z1}, with radius determined by Dose1. Or you could place points at {x1,y1,z1} with the color determined by Dose1.

Comment: @TimothyWofford `BubbleChart3D` is meant for that. Ali, it's really up to you what command you _want_ to use, look here at this list for a starter: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ChartingAndInformationVisualization.html

Answer (score 3):

Like I said in the comments, [`BubbleChart3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BubbleChart3D.html) is meant to do what [`ListPointPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html) is doing in this case. For example:

```
d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 4}];
BubbleChart3D[d]
```

[image: bubble1]

In this first example, the volume of the bubbles is proportional to the fourth element. To represent the fourth dimension with colors, we can do this:

```
BubbleChart3D[d, 
  BubbleSizes -> {0.02, 0.02},
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#4] &)]
```

[image: bubble2]

Answer (score 2):

Quick & dirty, the color represents the fourth coordinate :

```
d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 4}];
Block[{i = 1},
   ListPointPlot3D[d[[All, ;; 3]], 
         ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][d[[i++, 4]]]], 
         PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: after importing in mathematica, our data form is:{{x1,y1,z1,dos1},{x2,y2,z2,dos2},...}  are you sure i can plot these data with this commands??

Comment: @ali Take a look at his example data using `d[[1 ;; 5]]` -- it is exactly in this format.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

How about a grid of x vs y combinations. Here is an example in R http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.ca/2011/07/ Not difficult to do in Mathematica also, just not automatic.

```
a = Table[RandomReal[], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}];
x = Table[RandomReal[], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 100}];
y = a.x;

Table[ListPlot[Thread[{y[[i]], y[[j]]}], PlotLabel -> {i, j}], {i, 1, 
  3}, {j, 1, 3}] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Ian, RandomReal[] can receive parameters, so it's unnecessary to wrap it with a table. You can make your y in a single line. As for the charts, here's a more elegant example: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/enhanced-probability-and-statistics/perform-tests-of-independence-and-correlation.html

Comment: Yes and yes.  Good example. My example is obviously just thrown together.